# How to send emails using Amazon SES without verifying 'from' email address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ses

Can we send emails from Rails application using Amazon SES SMTP service where **sender's email ID is unverified.**?

I know that Amazon SES can send emails to unverified addresses. Is there any way to send emails from unverified arbitrary email address.

I want to know that, is there any way to get rid of it because my application is sending emails using  user's email addresses as sender's email address.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I got one solution for this problem. We can add arbitrary email address in From header of email along with the verified email address as follows

```
"arbitrarymail@example.com <verifiedemail@example.com>"
```

Because of this the receiver can get some Idea about the sender of the email.

Comment: And put the users arbitrarymail@example.com in the reply-to field.

Comment: Thanks this helped me out as well.

Comment: It replies to "arbitrarymail@example.com <verifiedemail@example.com>", not to "arbitrarymail@example.com".

Comment: Good idea. This solved my problem.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to send emails from any arbitrary email address using Amazon SES without verification.

You can however verify an entire domain, so that emails can be sent on behalf of all senders from the verified domain. If all your senders email addresses originate from a single domain, this solution will work, otherwise you may need to consider using an alternative to SES.

Announcement here: http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2012/05/15/amazon-simple-email-service-announces-domain-verification/

Comment: Hi, I got one solution for this.Check my answer!